# Excel compatibility in LabVIEW report generation

Tags: excel, labview

I am using LabVIEW 2018 and My excel template version is 2019. I can able to generate the report from my PC since I have an Excel version is 2019. If I am sharing the installer to other PCs that have 2013,2016 or any older excel versions, I could not generate the report due to the excel compatibility issues. I am getting the error "Error -2147352573 Member not found". 
My requirement here, is there any possible way to generate the excel report in other PCs that do not have the latest version of excel?

Opening the Excel routine:
[Code for Open Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4oLt.png)

Generate PDF routine:
[Code for generating PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NShvG.png)

[Error while generating PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkoHf.png)

Answer (score -1):

You should use (and maybe you already use) Report Generation Toolkit.

[Here](https://www.ni.com/it-it/support/documentation/compatibility/17/report-generation-toolkit-and-microsoft-office-and-labview-compa.html) you can find the compatibility matrix between Report Generation Toolkit and Office.

The executable must be generated on a system with the right Labivew and RGT version that match the Office versions you need to be compatible with.

Comment: @macro I think the question is he is already using RGT, but he wants to switch its version or ActiveX versions based on the EXCEL installed on the PC where his application is being used.

Comment: Hi @HaBo, the link I provided is the answer: the executable must be generated on a system with the right Labivew and RGT version that match the Office versions you need to be compatible with.

Comment: Edited the answer to include this explicitly